# Question about finding boolean variables in ANTLR

Tags: java, antlr4

given a full Java program Test.java that contains a variety of statements. What we are interested in are a special kind of statements: those boolean variables that are used as the condition of if statements. For example, in the following code snippets, quiet diag bail SLL are such boolean variables.

```
259:    if ( !quiet ) System.err.println(f);
            
271:    if ( diag ) parser.addErrorListener(new DiagnosticErrorListener());
272:    if ( bail ) parser.setErrorHandler(new BailErrorStrategy());
273:    if ( SLL ) parser.getInterpreter().setPredictionMode(PredictionMode.SLL);
```

Your task is to write code to find out such boolean variables with length > 3 and are only used without !. In your code you need to print out their name and line number. For example, the output for the code snippets above should be similar to this:

```
diag 271
bail 272
```

You are provided with a sample code JavaParserTest.java which has implemented the basic functionality of using the generated parser. For example:

```
CharStream input = new ANTLRFileStream(inputFile); // inputFile is "Test.java"
JavaLexer lexer = new JavaLexer(input);
CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
JavaParser parser = new JavaParser(tokens); //create parser
ParseTree tree = parser.compilationUnit();
ParseTreeWalker walker = new ParseTreeWalker(); // create standard walker
JavaListener listener = new JavaParserTest(); // create a parse tree listener
walker.walk(listener, tree); // traverse parse tree with listener
```

JavaParserTest is declared as a subclass of JavaListener and overrides the method enterStatement:

```
@Override
public void enterStatement(Java7Parser.StatementContext ctx)
{
    System.out.println("enterStatement");
    //your code starts here
}
```

The method above will be called when a Java statement is visited during traversing the parse tree. Your entire code will be written in this method.

Hints:
Check the Java8 grammar that `if` statement is defined at line 792: `'if' '(' expression ')' statement`. Hence, the boolean variables we are interested in must be in `expression`.
To determine if the first token in the current StatementContext `ctx` is `'if'`, use the following code:

```
if(ctx.getStart().getText().equals("if")) {
    //first token is 'if'
}
```

Right now, I can use `ctx.getStart().getLine()` to obtain the line number and use `ctx.getParent().getText()` to obtain the whole sentence whose start is "if", but I have no idea how to find the boolean variables in the parenthesis expression (also with the condition >3 and without "!"), can someone tell me how to do that?

Comment: Can someone help me solve this problem? Thanks

Comment: To solve this problem, print out the parse tree. Look at the various statement nodes, and explain how you would destinguish an "if statement" node from some other kind of statement. Then, work on the test expression.

Comment: Hey @kaby76, I can find the "if statement" because the getStart() can return the first token of this context, but I wonder how to find the boolean variable in this context? It looks like there's no way of retrieving context tokens by their index?

Comment: If you override the enterStatement() method, add code that tests the expression child node, something to the effect "ctx.parExpression().expression().getText().length() == 3", but you may need additional checks. Antlr generates methods like "parExpression()" for JavaParser.StatementContext so as to navigate down the parse tree to the child node you are interested in. Similarly, you could look up the tree using "parent". Take a look at the .java file generated by the tool.